# Not able to understand this graph property

Tags: graph, graph-theory, matching, vertex-cover

I read that in a simple graph, |minimal vertex cover| <= 2*|maximal matching|.

Consider a graph show here:-

[image: Graph]

Here a minimal vertex cover can be {B,C,D,E} which has a size of 4 and size of maximal matching is just 1.
So, 4>2*1 and the property doesn't seem to satisfy.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Minimal vertex cover of your graph is {A}

Comment: {A} is minimum vertex cover and not necessarily minimal. {B,C,D,E} is minimal because removing any of the vertex from this set will not satisfy the vertex cover property.

Comment: Yes, that's my fault. And where did you read about that inequality?